# Unable to access jarfile while starting a docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to run a dockerised springboot application as docker container.
While running the docker run command i am getting the error which says : "Unable to access jarfile".

**Non-Working Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk
COPY target/vol_demo.jar vol_demo.jar
ENV filePath=/tmp/test.txt
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN touch /tmp/test.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "vol_demo.jar"]
```

**Working Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk
COPY target/vol_demo.jar vol_demo.jar
RUN mkdir -p /tmp
ENV filePath=/tmp/test.txt
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "vol_demo.jar"]
```

Can someone tell me the reason why i am getting error in 1st case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COPY target/vol_demo.jar vol_demo.jar
WORKDIR /tmp
```

Where do you copy? Not into /tmp. You copy before setting workdir, so some previous from the image is used. The file was copied somewhere else.

Comment: (This is the same thing that would happen if you ran `cd /tmp; java -jar target/vol_demo.jar` outside of Docker.)